# How to Flip Adjacent Edges like this

Tags: rubiks-cube, mechanical-puzzles, twisty-puzzles

Only these two edges are misplaced. Any algorithm to solve this?

[image]

Comment: If blue is the front face... `F B L F2 L F' B D' F2 D2 L2 B2 R2 U' F2 R2`.

Comment: Thank you!! if you can post this as an answer I can accept :)

Comment: I like to use `F R' F' R' F2 L D R D' L' R' F2 R2` for your exact orientation where orange is F, Blue is R, and yellow is U

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Why so complicated? You can use even a simpler combo. First, move the other flipped edge to the opposite side. If BLUE is **F**ront and ORANGE is **L**eft do:

1. Moving the orange edge to the opposite side: **L', B'**
2. Combo to remember: **4x(M' U), 4x(U M')**
3. Moving back the orange edge to where it was: **B, L**

Basically you can flip sides on any two edges anywhere using this method.

P.S. **M'** - that's middle layer turning 90º in the same direction as **R**

Comment: Good answer for a rubik's cube, although if you're in a cube where the center piece rotation matters, like a ghost cube or a photo cube, this will also rotate two opposite centers on the equator 180 degrees.

Comment: Update: I just worked this out. This will reorient two opposite edges in place without upsetting the centers: `((U M)4 L (U M)4) L' ((U M)4 L M (U M)4) L' M'`. So on cubes where center rotation matters, you can move one adjacent edge to the opposite as described in this answer, and then do that.

Answer (score 7):

For this example, an algorithm that is more simple to remember, and can be altered for the other case (opposite edges), is this: `F' E F2 E2 F' U' F E2 F2 E' F and U`. Replace `U` and `U'` with `U2` for the case of flipping two opposite edges on top face.

(E is the equatorial slice, viewed from face U)

Comment: This used to confuse me, too, but Equatorial turns follow the the D layer. So if you were to put this algorithm into a cube solver as you wrote it, it wouldn't work. It should be `F' E' F2 E2 F' U' F E2 F2 E F U` and `F' E' F2 E2 F' U2 F E2 F2 E F U2` ([Slice Turns](https://ruwix.com/the-rubiks-cube/notation/advanced/#slice), [Solver](https://rubiks-cu.be/)) I still gave you an up vote since you did explain your atypical notation and gave a simple, reusable algorithm that covers both adjacent and opposite edge flips.

Answer (score 3):

You should learn how to use commutators as briefly sketched in [this post about general permutation puzzles](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1096592/21820). Then you would immediately know how to solve such states.

In particular, it is trivial to find a sequence A to first flip one edge without affecting the top face and then make a single turn B of the top face to move the other edge into that same position before undoing A and undoing B. This is, of course, a commutator A B A' B'.

Using this general approach you will find numerous solutions. One solution is as follows, assuming the two edges are at the front and right. First shift the edge to the middle horizontal slice (R) and then slice it away (E) before rotating the right face (R2) to be able to receive the edge via another slice (E2) before putting it back to the top face (R). That is, A = R E R2 E2 R and B = U'.

Answer (score 1):

I did M U M’ U M U M’ U M U M’ U

Comment: That also doesn't work because it swaps edges.

Comment: This actually does flip the required edges without swapping them (taking the blue face as front, and the M rotation in the same direction as R), but it also does a diagonal swap of the corners

Answer (score 0):

It's 2023 now so I guess you already have the answer but I am leaving this for the future generation of cubers. I am a beginner cuber and I do not know any advanced algorithms. I only know the basic ones.

This is happening because you have not formed the yellow cross yet. First you have to look for a flipped L shaped pattern in the top left corner of the Rubik's cube. If you don't have one then just rotate the upper piece until you get one. The photo that you have posted already has this pattern if you take orange as your front. Then apply this algorithm:
F R U R' U' F'.

Then you will get an horizontal yellow line in the middle. If you get a vertical line then just choose another face or rotate the upper piece(U or U') in any direction so that it becomes a horizontal line. Now apply the same algorithm:
F R U R' U' F'

Now your Rubik's cube shall have a cross and all the yellow colors in the edge pieces will be in the correct position. Now to match the edge with their centres you must use Sune algorithm. Or you can watch videos to solve the rest of the cube. Repeat the steps until you get a yellow cross.  If you already have horizontal line then simply apply the algorithm one time, you should have your yellow cross.

If you don't want to look for Sune algorithm then it is basically:
R U R' U R U' U' R'

But there are certain conditions you have to follow if you want to apply this algorithm so I really wish you to look into it in detail. I won't write much about it because the post has already become very big.

If you can't form a yellow cross no matter how many times you apply the algorithm, that means that you or someone else has tampered with your Rubik's cube. You need to disassemble the cube and assemble the cube again so that each piece is in the correct place.

Answer (score 0):

With orange as the front face do R, B, (M' U')2 M', U2, (M'
U')2 M, U2, B', R'

Answer (score -1):

***r U R’ U’ r’ U2 R U R U’ R2 U2 R***

Answer (score -1):

R U R' U' M' U R U' r'. This a standard CFOP OLL Algorithm

Comment: That doesn't work. It also swaps edges.